# Convert roman numbers into integers in a efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that receives Roman numbers and converts them to decimal. However I need to do a 
checker that analyzes whether the number is Roman or not. As the rule, a Roman number cannot have more than 3 letters "I" or "X" in the sequence, as it cannot have V more than 2 times in the sequence. How Can I do that comparing strings using for Loop?

```
for i in range(len(value)):
    if value[i] == value[i+1] and value[i+1] == value[i+2] and value[i+2] == value[i+3]: 
        print("It's not a Roman Number")
        break
```

I was only able to think of this code but if it contains the character more than 4 times the program will count the value, for example 'XIIII' = 14. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the check if the string is or not a roman use:

```
if s.count('X')>3 or s.count('I')>3:
    print("It's not a Roman Number")
```

Putting all together:

```
def my_rom_2_int(s):
    rom_val = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
    int_val = 0
    if s.count('X')>3 or s.count('I')>3:
        print("It's not a Roman Number")
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i > 0 and rom_val[s[i]] > rom_val[s[i - 1]]:
            int_val += rom_val[s[i]] - 2 * rom_val[s[i - 1]]
        else:
            int_val += rom_val[s[i]]
    return int_val
```

Output:

```
my_rom_2_int('XIIII')
It's not a Roman Number
14
```

Comment: of course. but the OP said "I was only able to think of this code but if it contains the character more than 4 times the program will count the value, for example 'XIIII' = 14"

Comment: my answer does exactly what OP asked for

Comment: There is another problem. I mean, I want to verify these numbers in the sequence.For example, If I put a numer like XXXIX it will return as 'Not a Roman Number', once it will count all characters. Would you know how to count only them in sequence? @seralouk

Comment: `'XXXIX'.count('X')` will return `4` so my line in the code `if s.count('X')>3 or s.count('I')>3:` will capture this and print `"It's not a Roman Number"`